# I want to downgrade my Android emulator in Android Studio to an older version, which version is better if you only have 8GB RAM on your PC?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have recently upgraded my machine to Windows 11. I only have 8GB of RAM on a Core I3 machine, so my resources are stretched to the limit. On top of that, I have an Android mobile development project I have to complete.

I found running Android Studio challenging, especially regarding the Emulator which keeps being terminated or is altogether unresponsive.

After searching, I found a post suggesting downgrading to an older Android Emulator. This is great if it works, however, I don't know which version of Android Emulator would be compatible with my machine.

The current spec requires 16GB RAM on 64-bit Windows OS.

I can test using my Android phone but I will need the emulator as well.

It was also suggested that I download as many emulator images as I required and test accordingly. If all else fails this will be the last resort.

The current Android emulator version installed is 32.1.13.

Thanks

Comment: I really suggest you get a new machine.  The speedup you'll get from better hardware will pay for itself in a few weeks.  You can get one under $200 on Amazon

Comment: That would be ideal. However, it is entirely impossible at the moment due to budgetary constraints.

Comment: Some third party emulators can be lighter than AS emulator, you can try one of them